# Command 'react-native run-android' got error

Tags: android, react-native

I install **react-native** on windows 10 from this official site([official doc](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.23/docs/getting-started.html#content))

And if I put command `react-native run-android`

I got error like this below

```
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
```

:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

**FAILURE:** Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101 contains a valid JDK installation.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

**BUILD FAILED**

> Total time: 19.959 secs Could not install the app on the device, read
>   the error above for details. Make sure you have an Android emulator
>   running or a device connected and have set up your Android development
>   environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

How to fix it?

Comment: java --version got: `
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer - need ind`JAVA_HOME` variable, as this image - 
[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [joxi.ru](http://joxi.ru/Q2Kn4D0I9KLbqm.jpg))</sub>

This version java must be **valid** and must contain `tools.jar` file. In my computer i have 2 versions, default version haven't `tools.jar` file.